# GCC assembly output: Get variables declared 'extern'

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am creating assembly code from C code with `gcc.exe -S -masm=intel -o filename.S filename.c`. I declared some variables as `extern` to allow later linking. I expected something like `extern variable` in nasm, but the variable is never mentioned in the assembly file.

Is there a way to check if a variable is extern or not? Or can I force gcc to add this information to the assembly file?

Comment: You used the variable in the code? Otherwise I believe the variable will not be mentioned. I made a little test and if I use the `extern` variable in the code, it's name is used in the assembly (but no `extern variable`). GCC 4.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `extern` variable is not mentioned in the assembly file, you're likely not using this variable. However, even if you were using it, you wouldn't see anything like `.extern varname` in assembly as well. GNU assembler treats all undefined symbols as external ones. GCC knows this and doesn't emit `.extern` directives. So look for, uhm, "PC-relative" variables (like in `mov eax, DWORD PTR varname[rip]`). That's your `extern` vars.